# Data Changing while dragging STRUCTURAL REFERENCING to right columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, excel-2013

I had written a formula in 2nd Column of 5 Column Table of Structural Refrencing of named ranges.
When I drag that formula to the right the refrences are changing as in 3rd column refrences become of 2nd column but I wnt it to be fixed at 1st column only. this can be done through normal cell refrencing by dollar sign.
BUT HOW TO DO IT THROUGH STRUCTURAL REFRENCING AND NAMED RANGES?